# How to return a value from loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

Hi I am using a method which have to returns the subsequent values from the loop.
But the return statement works outside the loop only.
How can I return the value within the loop?

Here is the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size (); i++)
{
    Iterator <String> it1 = //getting some list values
    double min = Double.parseDouble (it1.next ());
    double temp1 = 0;
    while (it1.hasNext ()) {
        if (it != null)
        {
            temp1 = Double.parseDouble (it1.next ()); 
        }                                   
        if (temp1 < min)
            min = temp1;
    } 
}
return min;
```

I want to return min value within the loop. How is it possible?
Please help me..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: You still need to loop through the whole list to find the min value so you can't return it from within the loop. If you want a neater way of doing this, you should create your own Comparator for your object so that you can do Collections.sort(myList<MyObject>) and get the min value thay way (first or last element depending on your Comparator)

Comment: Your iterator returns null, but says to haveNext?

Comment: What exactly do you want returned?

Answer (score 3):

It's done in the same way as returning outside of a loop, except that you need to ensure that your method will return a value under all circumstances (excluding uncaught exceptions, etc).  The following is your code with a return within the for loop.

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
{
    Iterator<String> it1 = //getting some list values
    double min = Double.parseDouble(it1.next());
    double temp1=0;
    while(it1.hasNext()){
        if(it!=null)
        {
            temp1 = Double.parseDouble(it1.next()); 
        }                                   
        if(temp1 < min)
             min = temp1;
    }
    return min; 
}
return 0;
```

Although that most likely doesn't implement your function correctly, it shows that returning within a loop is possible.  It also removes the need for a for loop altogether, but as I said before, that code is simply an example that shows returning within a loop is possible.

Comment: In this case, you do not need the `for` loop seen it always run for the first value only and it runs once only.

Comment: I know; I was simply showing that it's possible to return within a loop.  I didn't bother rewriting his method.

Comment: Okie. I got it. Actually, I don't know why he needs it because the logic is NOT fine. I think he even did not research about this before asking here.

Comment: He definitely did not, but regardless, no harm in helping him out :) Everyone has to start somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

A) You *can* `return` from a loop.

B) The more "structured" approach is to set a variable to some bogus/default value ahead of the loop, then set it to the valid value within the loop before executing a `break`.  Return the value on exit from the loop.

Comment: can you give some example? Please..I can't get it.

Comment: i tried. but still it shows error. i set variable outside of loop and return within the for loop. but shows error..